# Need to refresh Admin page twice to load it correctly in Magento 1.8.10

Tags: php, magento, nginx

I am trying to install vanilla magento 1.8.1.0 on a fresh new server, but after installation, on every admin page I go, I have to refresh the page twice to load it correctly.

When I just click on a link, only the header loads (without menubar) and the body is empty. If I refresh the page, it looks correctly. This happens sometimes on the front-end also, but happens always on the admin backend.

I have installed PHP 5.5 with OPCache on nginx on Ubuntu 13.10 server. There are no themes or plugins or any products created yet.

Any Ideas why this is happening?

Thanks,
Navneet

**First click on the link -**

[image]

*****Then I refresh the page to load it correctly *****

[image]

Comment: Did you try disable OPCache?

Comment: Yes, I tried that and it didnt help. However, I managed to go through the access and error logs of nginx to find the problem. The solution is simple - apt-get install php5-json

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that php5-json module was not installed on the server. With previous version of PHP it was installed by default, but not anymore.

There is a simple fix to it -

apt-get install php5-json

Hope this helps anybody else who ran into same issues while clean installing a server with all latest releases.